# Calculations on views From Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2d arrays looks like this:

`@forecast = [[6,2013,99],[7,2013,64],[8,2013,67],[9,2013,68],[10,2013,49]]`

And I want to get forecasting values of the data array

This code on view :

```
 <% tmp = '-' %>

 <% @forecast.each_with_index do |h, index| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= is_month?(h[0].to_s) + "-"  + h[1].to_s %></td>
   <td><%= h[2] %></td>
   <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif(index == 1) %> <%= tmp %> <% @aforecast = tmp %>
           <% elsif(index > 1) %> <%= @aaforecast = ((0.1* tmp.to_i)+(0.9 * @aforecast.to_i)).round %> <% @aforecast = @aaforecast %>
           <% end %>
   </td>
       <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif(index == 1) %> <%= tmp %> <% @bforecast = tmp %>
           <% elsif(index > 1) %> <%= @bbforecast = ((0.5* tmp.to_i)+(0.5 * @bforecast.to_i)).round %> <% @bforecast = @bbforecast %>
           <% end %>
   </td>
   <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif(index == 1) %> <%= tmp %> <% @cforecast = tmp %>  
           <% elsif(index > 1) %> <%= @ccforecast = ((0.9* tmp.to_i)+(0.1 * @cforecast.to_i)).round %> <% @cforecast = @fccorecast %>
           <% end %>
   </td>
   <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif (index == 1) %>
       <%= h[2].to_i - @aforecast.to_i  %>
           <% elsif (index > 1) %>
           <%= h[2].to_i - @aaforecast.to_i %>
       <% end %>
       </td>
   <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif (index == 1) %>
       <%= h[2].to_i - @bforecast.to_i  %>
           <% elsif (index > 1) %>
       <%= h[2].to_i - @bbforecast.to_i %>
       <% end %>
       </td>
   <td><% if(index == 0) %> - <% elsif (index == 1) %>
       <%= h[2].to_i - @cforecast.to_i  %>
           <% elsif (index > 1) %>
       <%= h[2].to_i - @ccforecast.to_i %>
       <% end %>
       </td>    
   <% tmp = h[2] %>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

The result looks like :

[image: finalresult]

Is there a way to resolve my case by just calling the array and calculates in views? or do I have another model to store all this and calling this model into view?

Thanks

Comment: I (and probably others too) don't understand the real problem. What does not work exactly?

Comment: @SebastianWramba : The problem is, can't get previous value of array for calculations. example, forecast for `jul-2013` get value from `qty(jun-2013)`, next forecast for `aug-2013` get from calculation `(a*qty(jul-13))+((1-a)*(forecast(jul-13))` etc. Sorry if this is long and confusing but i'll try to explain it as best as i can.

Comment: @SebastianWramba : I've updated the question.. The result is wrong.

Comment: Please replace the old code instead of adding new code.